# TypeScript & JQuery: event in handler "has not" properties 'target' and 'currentTarget'

Tags: jquery, typescript

I got `TS2339: Property 'target' does not exist on type 'Event'.` in below code:

```
this.$Element.on('click', SELECTOR, (event: JQuery.Event) => {
    const $ClickedLink: JQuery<HTMLElement> = JQuery(event.target);
    //
}
```

`event.currentTarget` is also does not exist, as ... defined in JQuery types?

Of course, there are no errors in compiled JavaScript.

**This code is not the Angular!** I just combine JQuery and class-based OOP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because the `@types/jquery` type for the event that is provided to a callback (as opposed to the `$.Event` function) is called `TriggeredEvent`, not `Event`:

```
this.$Element.on('click', SELECTOR, (event: JQuery.TriggeredEvent) => {
  const $ClickedLink: JQuery<HTMLElement> = JQuery(event.target);
  // ... snip ...
}
```